# Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type > 'OperatorFunction

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire

*component.ts*

`initialize()` method says

> Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'OperatorFunction<unknown[], unknown>'.   Type 'unknown[]' provides no
> match for the signature '(source: Observable<unknown[]>):
> Observable'

```
alertsChanged$: Observable<AlertModel[]>;

private initialize(): void {
  

    this.alertsChanged$ = this.alertsService.getAlerts().pipe(
      map((res) => res), // here it returns the above error
      tap((res) => {
        
        this.setDataForFilters(res); //Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AlertModel[]'.  
       
      }),          
    );
  }

 private setDataForFilters(alerts: AlertModel[]): void {}
```

*service.ts*

```
 // no issues here

 getAlerts(): Observable<AlertModel[]> {
      return this.angularFireDatabase
      .list<AlertModel>(`groups/${this.groupId}/alerts`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((res) => orderBy(res, ['timeStamp'], ['desc'])),
        first()
      );
  }
```

*.html*

```
 <app-alerts
    [alerts]="alertsChanged$ | async"
  ></app-alerts>
```

Please let me the issue here?

Comment: @Tony I need to use the `async` pipe on the template.

Comment: i think your problem is with orderBy function. maybe [this](https://mdmoin07.medium.com/sort-pipe-in-angular-6-7-f22475cc4054) medium can help you

Comment: @Dario No. I have removed that from the service and still it has the same error on the component. Any clue, please?

Comment: Could you please replicate the issue on a simple stackBiltz?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the issue here. It was a conflict with the `Lodash map` and `RxJS map`. i.e. VS code didn't import the RxJS map due to the Lodash map and it gave the above error due to that.

Since I need to use both on the same component I have done it like so.

```
import { finalize, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { map as lodashMap } from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 2):

The same kind of error will come if we use the imports from 'rxjs' and "rxjs/operators" at the same time. In my case this was the code,

```
  this.anApiCall.getAdata(this.id)
  .pipe(map(res => this.dataUtil.parseToForm(this.id, res)),
    onErrorResumeNext(of(this.dataUtil.newForm(this.id))))
  .pipe(tap(frm => this.form = frm))
  .subscribe();
```

I was using 'onErrorResumeNext' operator but unfortunately, IDE imported the function from 'rxjs' instead of rxjs/operators.

```
 import { onErrorResumeNext } from "rxjs"; // if the import is like this then you will get error like 'Argument of type 'Observable<YourType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.'
```

So check the import is from 'rxjs/operators' or not. and change the import as

```
import { map, tap, onErrorResumeNext  } from "rxjs/operators";
```