# Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, unknown>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to process an Observable in a method after a request via pipe (map) to use this corrected Observable in guard. But while writing the handler, I encountered the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, unknown>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<Object>): Observable<unknown>'.
```

Function with problem:

```
  isAccessToLobby() {
    return this.http
      .get(`${environment.domain}${BackendRoutes.Lobby}`, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(map((data) => data.allowAccess));
  }
```

The router:

```
router.get("/lobby", isAuth, (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
    allowAccess: true,
  });
});
```

Tried to define the Observable type for the argument, but didn't help.

Comment: Where did you import the `map` function from?

Comment: Could be `map` from `lodash`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69210119

Comment: I imported map from rxjs like this 
```import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';```
@Jakob Em @Benny

Comment: It was autoimport by IDIE. Possibly, this import is correct? ```import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';```

Comment: yes the compat import is probaly not the one you want. Does using the different import fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, everything is working now. Thanks for the tip about import. @Jakob Em

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the import from rxjs-compat causes the error.

```js
    import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';
```

Importing the map function from rxjs solves the error.

```js
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: All imports are now `import { map } from 'rxjs'`. No need to append `/operators`

Comment: Yes thats right @Benny for rxjs v7 and newer but for v7 rxjs-compat is not published anymore so the problem should not be an issue when using v7 or newer